# How do work database associations in microservices?

Tags: database, microservices

I'm currently researching microservices architecture and can't understand one thing.
Let it be api-gateway pattern.

For example i have two dbs:

1. Mongo which contains users and any auth data
2. Second for example postgreSQL which contains products

So if i use monolith architecture with one db, in product model i have createdBy property which contains key on user model. But how this associations work in microservices. Should i save just user id from mongo? Or it should be done in any another way?

Comment: Yeap. You would save a `GUID` Mongo generated on insertion for you. And you would take care to save it as raw bytes without reformatting it according to some unpopular format for example.

Comment: Thank you. Probably my question is very stupid. But for me microservices seems quite complicated thing. And this associations realization for some reason seemed for me too simple for this

Comment: Microservices _are_ quite complicated in general... (especially if you try to design them the way one would traditionally design a monolith)